# The disable method does not work on the Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to disable the checkbox through a condition, but it is not disabled.

I forcibly inserted the method in oninit and also checked in `console.log()` the form and it has `status: "DISABLE"` but the checkbox is not disabled, and if I insert a disabled data-binding in the checkbox the angular complains, saying that I'm using a reactive form and that I need to use the `.disabled()` method.

**CONTRACT FORM COMPONENT**

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-contract-form',
      template: `
        <app-form [class]="'flex__display align__items__center bg__color__red__light'" [fmGroup]="contractForm">
          <app-input
            (onclick)="onSubmitForm()"
            [class]="'cursor__pointer height__rem__2 width__rem__2 margin__xy__2'"
            [fmGroup]="contractForm"
            [fmControlName]="'termsAndConditions'"
            [type]="'checkbox'"
            [checked]="formValue"
          >
          </app-input>
    
          <app-span>
            Declaro que conheço e concordo com as
            <app-span
              (onclick)="clauseDocumentClick.emit(true)"
              [class]="'cursor__pointer text__color__blue__dark text__decoration__underline'"
            >
              Cláusulas Gerais do Contrato.
            </app-span>
          </app-span>
        </app-form>
      `,
    })
    export class ContractFormComponent implements OnInit {
      contractForm!: FormGroup;
      @Output() submitForm = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
      @Output() clauseDocumentClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
      @Input() protected set setDisabledForm(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this.contractForm.controls.termsAndConditions[isDisabled ? 'disable' : 'enable']();
      }
    
      constructor(protected readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.contractForm = formBuilder.group({
          termsAndConditions: formBuilder.control(true, Validators.requiredTrue)
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.contractForm.disable()
        console.log(this.contractForm)
      }
    
      get formValue(): boolean {
        return this.contractForm.controls.termsAndConditions.value;
      }
    
      onSubmitForm(): void {
        this.contractForm.controls.termsAndConditions.patchValue(!this.formValue);
        this.submitForm.emit(this.formValue);
      }
    }
```

**FORM COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="fmGroup" [class]="class" [autocomplete]="autocomplete" novalidate>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </form>
  `
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() fmGroup!: FormGroup;
  @Input() autocomplete = 'on';
  @Input() colectionText: string;

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**INPUT COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
  <input
  (click)="onclick.emit($event)"
  [formControlName]="fmControlName"
  [class]="class"
  [type]="type"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [autocomplete]="autocomplete"
  [minLength]="minlength"
  [maxLength]="maxlength"
  [readonly]="readonly"
  [autofocus]="autofocus"
  [checked]="checked"
  [required]="required"
 >
  `,
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onclick = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  @Input() fmControlName!: FormControlName;
  @Input() class = '';
  @Input() type = 'text';
  @Input() placeholder = '';
  @Input() autocomplete = 'on';
  @Input() minlength = 1;
  @Input() maxlength = 524288;
  @Input() readonly = false;
  @Input() autofocus = false;
  @Input() checked = false;
  @Input() required = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[image: r]

Comment: can you disable the terms and conditions on its own rather than the entire form? ngOnInit... `this.contractForm.get('termsAndConditions').disable()`

Answer (score 0):

As you are disabling entire form in `ngOnInit()`, then it should disable all controls inside the form including checkbox.

Check on stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms

If you want to disable specific control like checkbox based on some condition then you can use `this.contractForm.get('termsAndConditions').disable()`

Comment: I understood this, but he is not disabling the checkbox anyway.

It only disables the checkbox if instead of passing formControlName, I pass formControl to the input component.

However, if I do this it bugs and does not change the checkbox value.

Comment: Could you please share <app-input> component. You should bind the control with formControlName = 'termsAndConditions'

Comment: I posted the three components.

Comment: It seems like a typo mistake in InputComponent. There is '!'  after formControlName. @Input() fmControlName!: FormControlName. Same with the @Input() fmGroup!: FormGroup in FormComponent.

Comment: There is no typo.